# Passing user instance from one view to another in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and i am trying to pass user instance from one view to another and then save data in model Category but i get this error:

```
ValueError at /bookmark/category/
Cannot assign "45": "Category.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

bookmark is the name of my application.
After registering a new user, he is redirected to another page where he selects category from a dropdown list. I wish to add this selected category in Category model with the same userid.

This is my views.py code:

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = signUpForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            request.session['user'] = user.pk
            return render(request,'category.html')

def get_category(request):

    cname = request.POST.get("dropdown1")
    user = request.session.get('user')
    obj=Category(user=user,category=cname)
    obj.save()
```

This is models.py file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Can someone please guide if this is the right approach or something else is to be done?Thanks!

Comment: obj=Category(user_id=user,category=cname)

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal so the model Category is also to be changed:like user_id=models.ForeignKey(User) category=models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: No. When you just tell django to save user=user, django expects a user object in the right hand side. Since you haven't fetched the user object yet, you can just give the id which you already have in session. But this time you have to tell that it is id that I am passing so. user_id=user

Comment: What user are you trying to pass? The logged in user is passed with every request anyway

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Thanks but i get this error when i do user_id = user::IntegrityError at /bookmark/category/ NOT NULL constraint failed: bookmark_category.category

Comment: @Sayse The user which is created when i signup is to be passed

Comment: @SwatiSingh Are you sure you have value in cname field ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal How can i check that because i am doing this cname = request.POST.get("dropdown1"). Is it not the right way to fetch the selected element from the dropdown?

Comment: you can print.    print('value is....', request.POST.get("dropdown1"))

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Thanku.Yes i tried return HttpResponse(cname) it displays None that means cname is not getting the value from dropdown. What is the right way to retrieve the selected element from a dropdown list then?

Comment: Your method is not wrong. Need to take a look at your template. You should have the correct name, correct method etc.

Comment: Yes.Thanku:) The problem was in my template i was using <select multiple = "dropdown1"> instead of <select name = "dropdown1" multiple>.That is why no element was getting selected in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_category(request):

    cname = request.POST.get("dropdown1")
    user = request.session.get('user')
    obj=Category(user_id=user,category=cname)
    obj.save()
```

as user is a foreign key it needs an `User Instance` to get saved.

as you are having the id of the user you can use `user_id` for saving it

Comment: Thanks! So this means Model Category will be like this    user_id=models.ForeignKey(User)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: no, the thing you are having now in the model is perfect, you just need user_id in the category view to save it

Comment: Yes i did that also but i get this error :IntegrityError at /bookmark/category/
NOT NULL constraint failed: bookmark_category.category

Comment: this error means that the cname variable for the category is coming null, check it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to obj=Category(user_id=user,category=cname) there was also problem in my template.

I had written :

```
<select multiple = "dropdown1">
```

That is why i was getting Null constraint.

I modified it to

```
 <select name = "dropdown1" multiple>
```